# sort by ID variable R

Tags: r, sorting

I have data as follows. I want to rev sort the column "presum" within each id.

```
Obs hai_dispense_number   pdc1 dayscov2   pdc2 Time ID gh sr pre presum
1    1  Patient HAI0000072 1.0000       30 1.0000   -2  1  0  0   1     -1
2    2  Patient HAI0000072 0.0667        1 0.0333   -1  2  0  0   1     -2
3    3  Patient HAI0000072 1.0000       29 0.9667    1  3  1  1   0      0
4    4  Patient HAI0000072 0.0000        0 0.0000    2  4  1  2   0      0
5    5  Patient HAI0000072 0.0000        0 0.0000    3  5  1  3   0      0
6    6  Patient HAI0000072 0.0000        0 0.0000    4  6  1  4   0      0
7    7  Patient HAI0000072 0.0000        0 0.0000    5  7  1  5   0      0
8    8  Patient HAI0000072 0.4667       14 0.4667    6  8  1  6   0      0
9    9  Patient HAI0000072 1.0000       30 1.0000    7  9  1  7   0      0
10  10  Patient HAI0000072 0.9333       29 0.9667    8 10  1  8   0      0
11  11  Patient HAI0000072 1.0000       30 1.0000    9 11  1  9   0      0
12  12  Patient HAI0000072 0.3333       11 0.3667   10 12  1 10   0      0
13  13  Patient HAI0000072 0.8333       30 1.0000   11 13  1 11   0      0
14  14  Patient HAI0000072 0.9667       29 0.9667   12 14  1 12   0      0
15  15  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       30 1.0000   -6  1  0  0   1     -1
16  16  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       29 0.9667   -5  2  0  0   1     -2
17  17  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       29 0.9667   -4  3  0  0   1     -3
18  18  Patient HAI0000560 0.1000        3 0.1000   -3  4  0  0   1     -4
19  19  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       30 1.0000   -2  5  0  0   1     -5
20  20  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       29 0.9667   -1  6  0  0   1     -6
21  21  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       30 1.0000    1  7  1  1   0      0
22  22  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       29 0.9667    2  8  1  2   0      0
23  23  Patient HAI0000560 0.9667       29 0.9667    3  9  1  3   0      0
24  24  Patient HAI0000560 0.9667       28 0.9333    4 10  1  4   0      0
25  25  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       30 1.0000    4 11  1  5   0      0
26  26  Patient HAI0000560 0.9667       28 0.9333    6 12  1  6   0      0
27  27  Patient HAI0000560 0.9667       28 0.9333    7 13  1  7   0      0
28  28  Patient HAI0000560 1.0000       30 1.0000    8 14  1  8   0      0
```

I have tried this, to avail:

```
y<-df[sort(df$hai_dispense_number, df$presum),]
```

I know the difference between sort and order. I definitely want to sort here. I need the pdc2 values to retain their values in the order they are in. Just want to invert the presum variable.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any way to present your data so that is easily copied/pasted into R directly? It's not so easy to "guess" your columns in Excel...

Comment: @Rodrigo, please read `?read.table`, especially the `text` argument.

Comment: @Henrik it doesn't look like you've actually tried doing that for this data

Comment: @eddi & Rodrigo, sorry, my mistake. I ran into trouble to...;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(ID), transform,presum=sort(presum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the plyr package

```
library(plyr)
```

where `df` is your dataset

```
arrange(df, desc(presum))
```

Comment: Hi Vinchinzu, thanks for answer but unfortunately your solution does not work within id.

Comment: I'm against the use of external libraries for something that can be done with the basic ones. Matter of economy, agility, clarity? Can't name it...

Comment: @Rodrigo Since many libraries are built as wrappers around base `R` it is often the case that an operation can be done using only base `R`... However, it is also often the case that that would involve re-writing a large chunk of existing code that you have at your fingertips.  Avoiding packages is like navigating without a map...  You'll probably get there eventually but it will take a lot longer!

Comment: Yes, the old question of practicity vs. quality. When someone gets the habit of depending too often on external libraries, one gets too lazy to do the code, and sometimes uses a library for something that could be done in really few lines, and a small program ends up depending on many libraries. That's just against my philosophy of design. Of course I do use them, just try to avoid whenever possible. Anyway, it's just amazing to travel without maps sometimes ;)